# Weird table and graph

Tags: functions

So I was just messing around and created a table with the following data points https://www.desmos.com/calculator/je6witdw4o. Can someone please tell me what the function would be?

Data points:(-28,-23), (-21,-20), (-15,-17), (-10,-14), (-6,-11), (-3,-8), (-1,-5), (0,-2), (1,1), (3,4), (6,7), (10,10), (15,13), (21,16), (28,19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking first at the points where $x$ is nonnegative: notice that the $y$ values are increasing by a constant amount ($3$ each time), while the $x$ values are increasing by a linear amount (each increase is one more than the last). If we think of $x$ as a function of $y$, this indicates that it is a quadratic function of $y$ (essentially because its derivative is linear). Indeed, those nonnegative $x$ values are just the triangular numbers $\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}2$, where we want to plug in $n=0,1,2,\dots$ when $y=-2,1,4,\dots$; that is itself a linear function, giving $n=(y+2)/3$. So the nonnegative $x$-values are given by the formula
$$
x = \frac{(y+2)/3\cdot((y+2)/3+1)}2 = \frac{(y+2)(y+5)}{18} \quad(y\ge-2).
$$
Similarly, we want to get the values $-\frac{n(n+1)}2$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ when we plug in $y=-5,-8,\dots$, which leads to the formula
$$
x = -\frac{(-y-2)/3\cdot((-y-2)/3+1)}2 = -\frac{(y+2)(y-1)}{18} \quad(y<-2).
$$
So your "cubic" isn't a cubic at all, but a piecewise quadratic function.

PS: It would be nicer to potential helpers if you included all relevant data in your problem statement in a helpful format, rather than making people go to a different web site and process the data themselves.